Database integrity in mongo DB with hooks
I am trying to use mongo DB for my MERN app. So far I have used SQL databases where database integrity has never been an issue.
But mongo being No-SQL does not support foreign key relation which is giving me a hard time.
One solution I could think of is to have a pre-save hook to check if the keys exist. Will that make the system too slow. Is there any other way to achieve this.
I tried using pre-save hooks, so far no issue. It's just too much code to write in each model.

If you are aiming for consistency between different tables/collections, then the canonical way to do it in MongoDB would be keeping the data in the same table. Lookups/Joins are costly in MongoDB, so they should be avoided, both from consistency and performance perspectives.

You can use subdocuments in mongoose which are saved when the top-level of the document is saved - they are not stored in a separate collection. The data becomes denormalized. The downside is that if a subdocument appears in several parent documents you need to update them all. That's not an issue if the subdocuments don't change. NoSQL use case is different from SQL use case. Have you tried eating soup with a fork? I tried joining two forks together, then another but the integrity of my scoop was inconsistent. I didn't have that issue with spoons.
